# JSF 2 template itself shows style, but template client shows plain text without style

Tags: netbeans, jsf-2

I am trying to use JSF Facelet template/Facelet template client first time. I am creating template and template client with Netbeans 7.2.1. When I run that created JSF project and call `http://localhost:8080/jpaweb/template.xhtml` I can see template style, but when I call client template `http://localhost:8080/jpaweb/client.xhtml` I see plain text without style. Both files are in the same directory and created by Netbeans wizard. Please, help me with this issue.

template.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link href="./resources/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="./resources/css/cssLayout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <title>Facelets Template</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>


        <div id="top" class="top">
            <ui:insert name="top">Top</ui:insert>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div id="left">
                <ui:insert name="left">Left</ui:insert>
            </div>
            <div id="content" class="left_content">
                <ui:insert name="content">Content</ui:insert>
            </div>
        </div>
    </h:body>

</html>
```

client.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <body>

        <ui:composition template="./template.xhtml">

            <ui:define name="top">
                Welcome, to my website
            </ui:define>

            <ui:define name="left">
                My links
            </ui:define>

            <ui:define name="content">
                This page is created for testing
            </ui:define>

        </ui:composition>

    </body>
</html>
```

If you have Netbeans creating JSF project and JSF template and template client will get you this result. I tried in Netbeans 1.7.0 also. Same problem.

Edit: I run page not like `http://localhost:8080/jpaweb/client.xhtml` but like`http://localhost:8080/jpaweb/faces/client.xhtml` it worked. There is no "faces" directory in my project. Do we have to add "faces" to all JSF links?

Edit 2: I think netbeans auto-configures that all jsf files are kept in faces directory even there is no such directory in my project. And in Project properties -> Frameworks -> JavaServer Faces -> Configuration there is field JSF Servlet URL Pattern with value assigned /faces/*. I think that means one must call jsf files as if it is in faces directory. Trying to force it work as it appears in my project was a mistake :)

Comment: Some code would be helpful in order to better understand the concrete problem. Please make sure that you post the smallest possible code snippet which is sufficient in order to reprodcue your whole problem by just copypasting into a completely blank project with everything set to default. You seem namely to be generating code instead of writing code (which is an extremely bad idea when you're just starting, but ala).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Changed value of `Project properties -> Frameworks -> JavaServer Faces -> Configuration -> JSF Servlet URL Pattern` from `/faces/*` to `*.xhtml`, and that worked OK.

Answer (score 0):

Your **client.xhtml** content file is not properly composed. Don't include html tags, as JSF doesn't parse anything out from `ui:composition` tags here.

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
template="./template.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="top">
            Welcome, to my website
        </ui:define>

        <ui:define name="left">
            My links
        </ui:define>

        <ui:define name="content">
            This page is created for testing
        </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

I tested with your template and it works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that does not change anything, I think it auto creates faces directory when building project, look at my Edit and Edit 2 in question